# Get Unique Search Data When Join Providing Same Primary Key Value Multiple Times

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let me show the table structure

Book Table

```
DECLARE @Book TABLE (BookID INT, BookName VARCHAR(30))

INSERT INTO @Book
    (BookID, BookName)
SELECT '1', 'Art of Programming Contest' UNION ALL  
SELECT '2', 'Programming in C' UNION ALL
SELECT '3', 'Programming in C++'

--SELECT * FROM @Book
```

BookAuthors Table

```
DECLARE @BookAuthors TABLE (BookID INT, AuthorID INT)

INSERT INTO @BookAuthors
    (BookID, AuthorID)
SELECT '1', '1' UNION ALL
SELECT '1', '2' UNION ALL
SELECT '2', '1' UNION ALL
SELECT '2', '3' UNION ALL
SELECT '3', '2' UNION ALL
SELECT '3', '4'

--SELECT * FROM @BookAuthors
```

BookCategories Table

```
DECLARE @BookCategories TABLE (BookID INT, CategoryID INT)

INSERT INTO @BookCategories
    (BookID, CategoryID)
SELECT '1', '1' UNION ALL
SELECT '1', '2' UNION ALL
SELECT '2', '1' UNION ALL
SELECT '2', '3' UNION ALL
SELECT '3', '2' UNION ALL
SELECT '3', '4'

--SELECT * FROM @BookCategories
```

By using these tables, I want to search books by `BookID`, `AuthorID` and `CategoryID`; For `AuthorID` and `CategoryID` search, I need to join with `BookAuthors` and `BookCategories` table respectively. But When I try to search by `AuthorId`, the result gives me same `BookId` multiple times.

**Query**

```
SELECT BK.BookID, BA.AuthorID, BC.CategoryID 
FROM @Book BK
LEFT JOIN @BookAuthors BA ON BA.BookID = BK.BookID
LEFT JOIN @BookCategories BC ON BC.BookID = BK.BookID
WHERE BA.AuthorID = 1
```

**Result**

```
BookID  ----- AuthorID ----- CategoryID 
   1             1               1
   1             1               2
   2             1               1
   2             1               3
```

I think, Till Now It is good; Now, I want to generate the result like following:

```
BookID  ----- AuthorIDs ----- CategoryIDs
   1             1,2             1,2
   2             1,3             1,3
```

Any Idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simulating group\_concat MySQL function in Microsoft SQL Server 2005?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why you want your results to output like that, and I do not think it is a good idea.

But you can do it using the [**`stuff()`** with **`select ... for xml path ('')`** method of string concatenation](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/).

```
select 
    bk.BookId
  , AuthorIds = stuff((
      select ','+convert(varchar(12),ba.AuthorId)
      from @BookAuthors ba
      where ba.BookId = bk.BookId
      order by ba.AuthorId
      for xml path (''), type).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
      ,1,1,'')
  , CategoryIds = stuff((
      select ','+convert(varchar(12),bc.CategoryId)
      from @BookCategories bc
      where bc.BookId = bk.BookId
      order by bc.CategoryId
      for xml path (''), type).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
      ,1,1,'')
from @Book bk
where exists (
  select 1
  from @BookAuthors ba
  where ba.BookId = bk.BookId
    and ba.AuthorId = 1
  )
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/CVYKM71668

returns:

```
+--------+-----------+-------------+
| BookId | AuthorIds | CategoryIds |
+--------+-----------+-------------+
|      1 | 1,2       | 1,2         |
|      2 | 1,3       | 1,3         |
+--------+-----------+-------------+
```